# What is the significance of the magnitude/norm of BERT word embeddings?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

We generally compare similarity between word embeddings with cosine similarity, but this only takes into account the angle between the vectors, not the norm. With word2vec, the norm of the vector decreases as the word is used in more varied contexts. So, stopwords are close to 0 and very unique, high meaning words tend to be large vectors. BERT is context sensitive, so this explanation doesn't entirely cover BERT embeddings. Does anyone have any idea what the significance of vector magnitude could be with BERT?

Comment: There is quite detailed answer on stats.stackexchange - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177905/should-i-normalize-word2vecs-word-vectors-before-using-them

Comment: @PavelOganesyan No, Bert is not mentioned there at all. Moreover, the link only offers very general remarks about word2vec and vectors in general (of which the author of this OP is clearly aware, as his second sentence suggests)

Comment: @PavelOganesyan though it doesn't answer the question, your link does provide some very useful background info on word embeddings and handy references. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any difference in relation to cosine similarity or norm of a vector, between BERT and other embeddings like GloVE or Word2Vec. Its just that BERT is context dependent embedding so provide different embeddings of a word for different context.

Comment: By "no difference" you mean that larger norm indicates more specific (and less common) meaning?

Comment: I am somewhat doubtful that you are correct. Can you provide some justification?  BERT embeddings are generated via a completely different mechanism. eg: tokens are word pieces, embeddings themselves aren't passed through softmax over the vocab, instead the contextual rep. of the <MASK> token are. Without a strong argument to the contrary (ie: experiments that show it works that way), my guess is it's unlikely they will follow the same pattern.